# How can I set a background image to navigation controller bottom tool bar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, navigation

I have a navigation controller and I want to set an image to the bottom tool bar and and I want to add buttons to it how would I do this?

Comment: Do you mean a toolbar?  Your post does say tab bar, but the way you describe it makes me think you're talking of a toolbar.

Comment: yes
and how can i add buttons on it programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its usually best to read the Documentation a bit as it usually tells you things you to do.

For UIToolbar documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIToolbar/setItems:animated:)

Upon reading this you can see there is a setItems which takes an NSArray of UIBarButtonItems.

Your best bet is probably something along these lines. Assuming you want to be able to Use Images for the buttons. If not, let me know and I can update the answer.

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBlack target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];

[array addObject:button1];

[toolbar setItems:arrayOfButtons];
```

Comment: yes for buttons i want to add image and for the tool bar aswell..
i mean i want to see my image as a tool bar upon that these buttons will be there